# AppJar threading to allow for GUI updates

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have been studying the AppJar documentation for the last few hours, but I really can't seem to figure out how to get the GUI to update during the data processing. I split the 4 main functions into different threads, and within the threads I added the update function as a .queuefunction, but the GUI still hangs until everything has completed.

This is the update function I wrote:

```
label_status = ["Ready"]


def update_label():
    app.setLabel("status_label", label_status[-1])
```

I then broke down the process into 4 threads, but it didn't change anything compared to before. So I'm guessing I missed something pretty obvious here, but I can't find it.

```
def press(button):
    """ Process a button press

    Args:
        button: The name of the button. Either Process of Quit
    """
    if button == "Process":
        global label_status
        global output_directory
        global filename_out
        src_file = app.getEntry("input_file")
        output_directory = app.getEntry("output_directory")
        filename_out = app.getEntry("output_name")
        errors, error_msg = validate_inputs(src_file, output_directory, filename_out)
        if errors:
            label_status.append("Error")
            update_label()
            app.errorBox("Error", "\n".join(error_msg), parent=None)
            return label_status
         else:
        #Create single xlsx doc from data
        trimmed_input = src_file[:-4]
        app.thread(create_xlsx_file(trimmed_input))

        # add graphs to excel file
        app.thread(add_graphs())

        #clean temporary files
        app.thread(clean_files())

        #move output.xlsx to location chosen with filename chosen
        app.thread(move_output())
```

I have attempted to update the GUI within in threads in the following way:

```
def clean_files():
    label_status.append("Cleaning temporary files")
    app.queueFunction(update_label())
    file_path = os.path.join("csv_output/" + "temp*")
    del_files = glob.glob(file_path)
    for files in del_files:
        os.remove(files)
```

Since I'm appending to a list, I can see all statuses are being added, but only the first and last are displayed to the user. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all your calls to `app.thread()` and `app.queueFunction()` are being done wrong.

I think you should be passing just the name of a function. But, because you’ve put brackets after the function names, you’re actually passing the result of the functions.

Try it without including brackets after the function names, eg. `app.queueFunction(update_label)`

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this. Your suggestion kind of works, but the threading causes problems with the code. I imagine by their nature, threads execute simultaneously? Because it seems like fourth thread is happening before the second, hence I can't add graphs to the file because the file has already been moved. Anyway, it's not a huge problem for now, and if the program encounters an error, at least the status reflects at which step it got stuck.

Comment: In which case, move the calls to `create_xlsx_file()`, `add_graphs()`, `clean_files()` & `move_output()` into a function, then thread that function.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't the label only update when all the functions have run? Which is what happens at the moment anyway

Comment: I don’t think so. Each call to `queueFunction()` is processed by the main GUI thread, so should get updated as each happens.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything, still hangs for a few seconds and then the status jumps to 'complete'.

Comment: It may just be that some of the functions finish so quickly that you don’t see the gui change? Try putting a pause between each function call...

Comment: Hmm, still nope. I tried `time.sleep(5)`, and it just hangs until everything is complete. Throwing a `gui.infoBox` in between calls will cause the label to update, but that's not really useful in practice.

Comment: `update = tkinter.Toplevel()` `update.update()` seems to work, although this results in another window popping up. I can then use `update.withdraw()` to get rid of it. But yeah, obviously not the most elegant of solutions...